# Is this question correctly closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Subject question: [Novel with plot element of a water world with multi-armed creatures which communicate by joining arms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72855/novel-with-plot-element-of-a-water-world-with-multi-armed-creatures-which-commun)

The accepted answer to it is "Fleet of Worlds" but it's closed as a duplicate of
[Novel where a man is paid to travel to a planet inside a metallic sphere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94578/novel-where-a-man-is-paid-to-travel-to-a-planet-inside-a-metallic-sphere) which has an accepted answer of "Ringworld"

Are they duplicates because the two different books are in the same series? That seems a stretch.

Comment: Rather than waiting on the outcome of this meta, I see that (Moderator) Thaddeus has decided to take unilateral action; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/141211, as has (Moderator) Kevin; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/72855/timeline#history_f8f6dc39-4236-41bd-a069-7c7dada4ec4b.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be a dupe.  I have nominated it for reopening.